# Google Fonts vs Opera

Tags: html, css, шрифты, google-fonts

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой: в **Opera** не отображается текст кастомным шрифтом "Cuprum", если в стиле прописано свойство `font-weight:bold;`, хотя в остальных браузерах (**Chrome**, **IE+8**, **FF**, **Safari**, **Netscape**) отображается всё нормально. Если задать свойство `font-weight:lighter!Important;`, то **Opera** отображает кастомный шрифт!

Как это можно обойти, подобрать похожие или использовать какие-то "костыли"?
Всё-таки хотелось бы использовать полужирный шрифт!

Спасибо!

Comment: Что за олень всем минусы проставляет?)

Comment: @Cone сам не знаю, но тоже за участников обидно. Выравниваю, кто незаслуженно получил.

Comment: Netspace???

Comment: Кому-то "америку открыл"  что есть Netsсаpe Navigator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если [здесь](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cuprum) вы видите его жирным (а у меня именно так в опере), то значит ошибка у вас. Может быть у вас локально установлен Cuprum ? Или вы его неправильно подключаете? Попробуйте назначить ему название отличное от Cuprum при подключении.

Comment: Opery сносил по новой ставил свежий дстр, купрум в шрифтах есть, но в других браузерах отображается как надо! Скорее всего опера нормально не встает!

Comment: В font-face font-family поменяйте с Cuprum на иное имя для этого шрифта, не используйте src local. И везде используйте это изменённое название. У меня у самого в опере опен санс прозрачный на некоторых сайтах.